# Avoiding landing page redirects via custom apache module

Tags: c, apache, redirect, request, internal

I'm creating an apache module that prevents users from going through a chain of redirect pages to retrieve the page they finally want. This is my code so far:

```
#include "httpd.h"
#include "http_config.h"
#include "http_protocol.h"
#include "ap_config.h"
#include "http_log.h"

static int subreq_handler(request_rec *r){
    if(ap_is_initial_req(r)){
    r->content_type = "text/html";
    apr_table_set(r->headers_out, "Hostname","127.0.0.2");
    request_rec* rr=ap_sub_req_method_uri("GET","/folder",r,NULL);
    if (rr){
        char *l=apr_table_get(rr->headers_out, "location");
        ap_rprintf(r,"redir=%s\n", l);
        ap_rprintf(r,"rr->status=%d\n", rr->status);
        ap_destroy_sub_req(rr);
    }
    return DONE;
    }
}

static void subreq_register_hooks(apr_pool_t *p){ap_hook_fixups(subreq_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_FIRST);}
module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA subreq_module={STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,subreq_register_hooks};
```

The code returns status 301 which is good when I replace `/folder` in my code with an actual folder name without a slash and the redir value is also correct and filled in with the entire new URL.

I want this to happen with any URI request but when I tried requesting a PHP file instead (replaced `/folder` with `/path/to/file.php`) that contains instructions to redirect, the status returned is 200 when it should be 301.

The following is the PHP code used in the PHP file.

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved",true);
header("Location: /",true);
?>
```

Does anyone know how to make an apache sub-request to any domain on the local network and to any file and have the file return the true status and if the status is 301, have it return the new true location? If so, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

What about using **ErrorDocument**?

If the user requests a file that isn't found where requested, ErrorDocument 404 could load a .php page that searches for the file.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html

Comment: File not being found is a different story. What I'm trying to do is *reduce the number of redirect chains* so that instead of a user being redirected to a redirect then a redirect then a redirect, etc, the user only will be redirected once.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Maybe it would help others to give you a better answer if you posted the redirects you are trying to reduce.

Comment: Every single one. Its hard to identify them all as this code is going to a back end of a server that hosts many websites, so I'm doing every guest a favor by (trying to make) one module that reduces the required redirects to one at most.